# Is there a conventional way to create a tensor with a variable elements in tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to implement a machine learning model from a research paper into tensorflow which requires that I create a tensor block diagonal matrix. In the paper, they give the formula for the block which looks something like

```
[[cos(x * theta_1), sin(x * theta_2)], [-sin(x * theta_3), cos(x * theta_4)]]
```

I've made a function in tf which takes in x and returns a diagonal matrix but this matrix is going to be utilized hundreds of thousands of times over a training cycle so I'd like to find a way to avoid creating it from scratch every time I need to use it. Unfortunately, because x could be any real number within a range, I can't just create a matrix for every possible value of x and store them in a list for later use.

I'm wondering if there is a way to create the matrix such that it includes the variable x in some of its elements so that I can do something like

```
 "create_tensor_from_schematic(tensor_with_variables, value_of_x)"
```

and it will 
return the tensor evaluated for that value of x, saving me from having to reconstruct the diagonal matrix every time.

This matrix is a key component in a function that sits right in the middle of my model and is utilized by every training and testing sample once every epoch. Here's the code for that matrix:

```
def build_D(self, n, j):
    def theta(k):
      return (2 * math.pi * k) / n

    def A(k, j):
      j_thetak = j * theta(k)
      return tf.convert_to_tensor([[math.cos(j_thetak), math.sin(j_thetak)],
                                   [-math.sin(j_thetak), math.cos(j_thetak)]], dtype=tf.float32)

    if n % 2 == 1: #n is odd
      s = int((n - 1) / 2)
      block_list_A = [tf.reshape(tf.convert_to_tensor([1], dtype=tf.float32), [1, 1])] + [A(k, j) for k in range(1, s + 1)]
    else: #n is even
      s = int((n - 2) / 2)
      last_term = (-1) ** j
      block_list_A = [tf.reshape(tf.convert_to_tensor([1], dtype=tf.float32), [1, 1])] + [A(k, j) for k in range(1, s + 1)] \
      + [tf.reshape(tf.convert_to_tensor([last_term], dtype=tf.float32), [1, 1])] 

    return tf.linalg.LinearOperatorBlockDiag(list(
        map(lambda x: tf.linalg.LinearOperatorFullMatrix(x), block_list_A))).to_dense()
```

(this version of the code is the one I'm currently using which only supports integer valued j which allows me to just create the matrix for every j within my range and store them in a list but In the future j will be real valued and I obviously can't create a matrix for every possible j value.)

j is the only variable that changes, so it would be nice if there was a way to run this once and to keep just copy the j's over into the matrix for evaluation when I need the matrix which corresponds to a certain j value.

I wondered if it was possible to create a tensor with lambda expressions as elements but I can't imagine how I could pass an argument to them.

Is there an inbuilt conventional way to create a something like a tensor schematic in `tensorflow`? What are my options? Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem? You have a function that takes `x` as input and returns your tensor as output. `x` can vary so you need to calculate the tensor when it's needed? What is it that you are trying to avoid? Just call that function inside your training loop, no?

Comment: The function is quite complicated so it seems inefficient to create a new block diagonal matrix for every training example when the only thing changing is that x. I just thought it would be more elegant if there was a way to create a tensor like `[2x, 5x]` that I could store in a variable like a schematic and then evaluate by like `tensor_from_shematic(schematic, x_val)` which would return the evaluated tensor.

Comment: But the processor still has to do the sums for each value regardless, no? Ultimately that tensor needs to be a matrix of *numbers* to enable training to take place. You can (probably) create an OPERATION (or set of ops) that represents your abstract matrix but, ultimately, it's going to need to be calculated so what's wrong with the abstraction being the function? (Which is, in essence, just a set of operations!)